# In SQL Server, how do I get the latest dates with multiple columns of dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

This feels like it should be an easy one.  How do I get the latest of 3 dates that are in different columns

```
DROP TABLE #dates
CREATE TABLE #dates (mykey CHAR(10), date1 DATETIME, date2 DATETIME, date3 DATETIME)
INSERT #dates VALUES ('Key1', '1/1/2015', '2/1/2015', '3/1/2105')
INSERT #dates VALUES ('Key2', '1/2/2015', '4/2/2015', '3/2/2105')
INSERT #dates VALUES ('Key3', '1/3/2016', '4/3/2015', '3/3/2105')

select mykey, ?? AS 'Latest Date' from #dates
```

I would like the result to be:

```
mykey       Latest Date
Key1        2105-03-01 00:00:00.000
Key2        2015-04-02 00:00:00.000
Key3        2016-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: You can easily achieve it using `MAX` from derived table based on `UNION ALL/VALUES` multiple columns

Comment: I re-opened the question because I think the below answer is better than the referenced duplicate question.

Comment: date3 should be in 2015 as well, not in 2105 in order to get the results you wanted, otherwise it will return date3 for all of the keys

Comment: Ideally, fix your data model. All data of the same "type" (such that it makes sense that two values will be compared to each other) ought to be in a single column. When you have numbered columns, it's usually a sign that data has ended up embedded in metadata (i.e. 1, 2 and 3 are *meaningful*, but there's no way to write straightforward queries that use those numbers) or you have arbitrary restrictions (why does it stop at 3?)

Answer (score 8):

Probably the easiest way in SQL Server is to use `cross apply`:

```
select d.*, m.maxdate
from #dates d cross apply
     (select max(dte) as maxdate
      from (values (date1), (date2), (date3)) as v(dte)
     )  m;
```

Comment: even though it is good query it is not giving exact result as mentioned in output

Comment: @mohan111 . . . Presumably, the 2105 year is a typo in the sample data, based on the context of the question.  Here is a SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a52e6/2.

Comment: No Exactly we need to get 2016 for key3 but In your query it is showing other value we need to MAX means highest date

Comment: @mohan111 . . . If I change the years in the third column, it returns 2016:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09613/1.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `CASE` statement would get the job done.

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE (mykey CHAR(10), date1 DATETIME, date2 DATETIME, date3 DATETIME)
INSERT @dates VALUES ('Key1', '1/1/2015', '2/1/2015', '3/1/2105')
INSERT @dates  VALUES ('Key2', '1/2/2015', '4/2/2015', '3/2/2105')
INSERT @dates  VALUES ('Key3', '1/3/2016', '4/3/2015', '3/3/2105')

select mykey, 
case when date1 >= date2 and date1 >= date3 THEN date1
    when date2 >= date1 and date2 >= date3 then date2
    else date3 end [LatestDate]
 from @dates
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use `iif` statement:

```
SELECT mykey
    ,iif(month(date1) > month(date2), iif(month(date1) > month(date3), date1, date3), iif(month(date2) > month(date3), date2, date3)) AS result
FROM #dates
```